# Python's Pool map hangs when subprocess killed

Tags: python

I'm banging my head on more than a day now, trying to understand why my program's children can't raise any exception and simply die, instead of making the whole `Pool` hangs. Let me add that I searched on the internet for hours, haven't found something related.

Let's consider as an example:

```
#!/opt/perforce/bin/python/3.4.2/bin/python3

import multiprocessing
import sys


def run(i):
    print(i)
    sys.exit(1)

iteration = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
    pool.map(run, iteration)
    print("reached here ?")
```

With the `sys.exit()`, the print is never reached, `pool.map` hangs blocks for some reasons. On my real script, the `sys.exit()` has been added when I catch some kind of errors. I'd like to be able to gracefully kill a worker (or simply make it skip the iteration, like a break). I tried `sys.exit()`, `exit()` or even `os.kill()`, but no luck...

Is it possible?

Comment: Which `print` isn't reached? The one that says 'reached here ?' or the one(s) inside `run()`?

Comment: the print "reached here ?". I'm wondering why my pool.map never ends. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, you raise an Exception and catch it outside of the callable.  Like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import sys


def run(i):
    print(i)
    if i == 'test3':
        raise Exception()

iteration = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:
    try:
        result = pool.map(run, iteration)
    except Exception:
        sys.exit(1)
    print("reached here ?")
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to exit the whole pool as you seem to suggest. Otherwise I would use pool.terminate. I just want to let the current iteration pass and die without blocking the whole pool.

Comment: @GuillaumeFenollar `Pool.map()` is intended to be *safe*. And if you run it on N items, it should return N results. If child process dies in the meantime, then something went wrong. Consider catching exceptions in the child process and return error value instead of killing the whole child process (which feels wrong IMO).

Comment: It works indeed with a set of return when my subprocess has an issue.  It's a bit ugly because I have a big tree of functions and I have to use several return to go back to my __main__ function, where pool.map is triggered, but it works. I understand your point here, but I still regret there's not a way to gracefully terminate a pool.map process (as it exists with Process.terminate()).
Thanks Yaroslav